# TypeError : is not a function in Google Apps Script (MailApp code)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, typeerror

I'm trying to send an email through Google Apps script, but I can't load the attachment.

The file name and variable appear to have been defined, but the following message appears, and the code does not execute.

TypeError: paymentPDF.getAs is not a function

How should I fix it?

```
function test() {
  
  var noteSheet = getSheetById(noteSheet id); 
  var paymentSheet = getSheetById(paymentSheet id); 

  var emailTitle = noteSheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var emailContent = noteSheet.getRange(3,2).getValue();
  var emailRecipient = noteSheet.getRange(4,2).getValue();

  var fileName = paymentSheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var paymentPDF = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("file id");
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailRecipient, emailTitle, emailContent, {
      name: 'test name',
      attachments: [paymentPDF.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, `paymentPDF` is FileIterator. I thought that by this, such an error like `TypeError: paymentPDF.getAs is not a function` occurs. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var paymentPDF = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
```

#### To:

```
var paymentPDF = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
if (!paymentPDF.hasNext()) {
  throw new Error("No file.");
}
var paymentPDF = paymentPDF.next();
```

- In this modification, it supposes that the file of `fileName` is only one in Google Drive. When the file of `fileName` is not existing, an error like `No file.` occurs. When the file of `fileName` is existing, the file object is returned. By this, `paymentPDF.getAs(MimeType.PDF)` can be used.

#### Reference:

- [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String))

Comment: I solve this problem for your comment. Thank you Tanaike :)

Comment: @Sehyeon Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.